# my fullcalendar only lists 1 event out of 3 that I have with for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I put in context I have my full calendar that only lists 1 event and does not list the others I have reviewed the code and maybe I need a bit of logic but I can't find what is happening, then I attach code with explanation

```
 /*  Initialize the calendar  */
        var ide = document.getElementsByName("id");
        var fecha = document.getElementsByName("fecha");
        var nombre = document.getElementsByName("nombre");
        var horaInicio = document.getElementsByName("horaInicio");
        var horaFin = document.getElementsByName("horaFin");
        var id="";
        var dia = "";
        var titulo = "";
        var inicio = "";
        var fin = "";

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var form = '';
        var today = new Date($.now());
        var citas=[];
       for (var x = 0; x < nombre.length; x++) {
            var defaultEvents =[{
                    id: id + ide[x].value,
                    title: titulo + nombre[x].value,
                    start: dia + fecha[x].value + 'T' + inicio + horaInicio[x].value,
                    end: dia + fecha[x].value + 'T' + fin + horaFin[x].value
                }];
                citas.push(defaultEvents);
            } 

            var $this = this; 
            for (var i=0;i<citas.length;i++){
            $this.$calendarObj = $this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
                events: citas[i]
            });
            }
```

At the beginning I am collecting values that come from my jsp file, I create a for loop where I create an object and in this object each one of the events goes and then I add them in an Array of name (citas) and this would be my result in my console
[image]

this is what it shows on my console.
After this I make another for loop which is the one that has to list each of the events by calling the array and listing each of the positions and as a result it lists 1 event out of 3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two logical errors I can see:

1)

```
var defaultEvents =[{ ... }]
```

This creates an array with an object in it. You then push this array into the `citas` array. Therefore your events structure is an array of arrays (where each array contains one object). But fullCalendar expects an array of objects.

So change this to

```
var defaultEvents = { ... }
```

instead.

2)

```
for (var i=0;i<citas.length;i++){
    $this.$calendarObj = $this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
        events: citas[i]
    });
}
```

This just makes no sense. What your code says here is "loop through the citas array. For each item in the array, re-declare `$calendarObj` as a new calendar and give it the next array from `citas` as the events".

As you can see, this overwrites your calendar every time, and so you'll just end up with a calendar containing the last array entry you added to citas - which as we've seen, only contains one event.

If you make the change I mentioned in point 1, then setting up your calendar to contain all the events becomes trivial - just alter the above code to:

```
$this.$calendarObj = $this.$calendar.fullCalendar({
    events: citas
});
```